# python parallel loop: communicate to outside

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing

I am trying to run a parallel loop (disclaimer: I am new to parallel processing and this might be quite a dumb question).
Essentially I want to be able to start and terminate a loop, within a parallel function **and be able, from time to time, to check on its state.**

I tried writing a very basic example (see below), using  multiprocessing Process and Queue, where a child function is started and begins looping. At each iteration it adds a value to the queue, so it can be communicated to the outside. However the value that I get from the queue is resulting instead from the how many times I asked for queue.get().

Run the code and the issue might make more sense.
Alternative and simpler way of doing it are much appreciated.

```python
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q): 
    z = 0
    while True:
        z = z+1
        print 'z', z
        q.put(['f is at z value {}'.format(z)])
        time.sleep(float(0.1))        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    process = Process(target=f, args=(queue,)) 
    process.start()
    print 'start with z value:'
    print queue.get()
    time.sleep(1)

    print 'now f is at z value:'
    print queue.get()

    time.sleep(1)        
    print 'terminating with z  value:'
    print queue.get()    
    process.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) or [`Value`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) from `multiprocessing` to [share the state](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) between the processes:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def f(v):
    z = 0
    while True:
        z = z+1
        print 'z', z
        v.value = z
        time.sleep(float(0.1))        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    value = Value('i')
    value.value = -1
    process = Process(target=f, args=(value,))
    process.start()
    print 'start with z value:'
    print value.value
    time.sleep(1)

    print 'now f is at z value:'
    print value.value

    time.sleep(1)        
    print 'terminating with z  value:'
    print value.value
    process.terminate()
```

Output:

```
start with z value:
-1
z 1
z 2
z 3
z 4
z 5
z 6
z 7
z 8
z 9
z 10
now f is at z value:
10
z 11
z 12
z 13
z 14
z 15
z 16
z 17
z 18
z 19
z 20
terminating with z  value:
20
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a [shared Value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def f(z):
    while True:
        z.value += 1
        print 'z', z.value
        time.sleep(float(0.1))        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    z = Value('i', 0)

    process = Process(target=f, args=(z,)) 
    process.start()
    print 'start with z value:', z.value
    time.sleep(1)

    print 'now f is at z value:', z.value

    time.sleep(1)        
    print 'terminating with z  value:', z.value

    process.terminate()
```

PS your original example doesn't work because you add something to the Queue every time round the loop...

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [queue guide](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get), Queue.get()

> Remove and return an item from the queue.

This means that it accesses the objects sequentially: it removes the first one, then the second, etc... This behavior is normal, since a queue works FIFO (first in, first out).

Thus, the first time you check the queue content Queue.get() removes the first element in the queue. At this time there is just one element in the queue.

The second time you check, Queue.get() removes the second element in the queue. At this time there are 9 elements in the queue (the first was already removed); but you are accessing the second only.

The third time you check the queue, you remove the third element, but in the queue there are 18 elements (you already removed the 1st and 2nd element)

To see this behavior in action, add the following line before checking the queue:

```
print 'Queue size: {}'.format(queue.qsize())
print queue.get()
```

The problem is that if you want to check the current state of the process, the queue is not the way to do so, since it *queues* the messages, it **does not** *report* on current state.

Answer (score 0):

A class would be a better structure to handle state request instead of a function. Try this :

```
class MyProcess():
  def __init__(self):
    self.state = None

  def start_process(self):
    #manage your state handling here or in an other method.
    self.state = "set state"

p = MyProcess()
queue = Queue()
process = Process(target=p.start_process, args=(queue,)) 
process.start()
print(p.state) #get the state
```